# Find Bugs Plugin Bug type NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, findbugs

I am having following piece of code which is failing findbugs plugin:

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean bean= createSessionFactory(dSource);
if(bean!=null) 
reader.setSessionFactory(bean.getObject()); // this line fails.
```

Error is :

Bug type NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE.

I am using bean object only after checking for null , why does it fails?

Update : I am able to resolve as follow:

```
if(bean!=null)
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = bean.getObject();
        if(sessionFactory!=null)
        reader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }
```

but following does not work:

```
if(bean!=null)
    {
        if(bean.getObject()!=null)
        reader.setSessionFactory(bean.getObject());
    }
```

I am not sure what happened.

Comment: `getObject` could return `null`. If this is an `@Configutation` class you should use different constructs (generally when doing things like this you are doing the wrong thing).

Comment: I changed if statement as :   if(bean!=null && bean.getObject()!=null)
    reader.setSessionFactory(bean.getObject());   still getting same error. The description says "The return value from a method is dereferenced without a null check, and the return value of that method is one that should generally be checked for null. This may lead to a NullPointerException when the code is executed"

Comment: As I mentioned you shouldn't be calling `getObject` as that is what spring should do. Looks like you are manually configuring a `SessionFasctory` and pass it to a spring batch reader. Is there a reason you don't let this be handled by Spring?

Comment: But why does it matter to find bugs if I use getObject.This is the existing code and i am trying to add findBugs plugin to it.What can be the workaround?From the description it seems that the "bean" variable returned from function should be checked for null